# how to create a simple animation in the taskbar?

Tags: java

for my little program I'd like to create a simple notification just like this(for example):

[image]

I do not know where to start, Any helps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something in the taskbar (next to the clock) or something that pops up an animation like that too?

There is a brief (but good place to start) doc here for the system tray:
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/

Also have a look into the Swing timers, they can help you create animations:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html